# Spring Boot expression based access control property not found

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-el

I am exposing some entities using Spring-data-rest and I would like to configure acess control using Spring expression language and preauthorize so that user can manipulate only entities that belong to him.

My principal object contains the user id in its username (String) and user has a property id (Long):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Getter
@Setter
public class User {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
  private Long id;

  ...

}
```

My repository looks like this:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

  @Override
  @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
  User findOne(Long id);

  @Override
  @PreAuthorize("#user.id == principal.username")
  void delete(User user);

  ...

}
```

However, when calling `DELETE /users/1` when authenticated as a user with id `1` (principal contains this id in its username), I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to evaluate expression '#user.id == principal.username'
...
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'id' cannot be found on null
```

I based my expression on the official [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html). Can someone point out what am I missing here?

EDIT:
I added all the methods in my repository, since they seem to be interconnected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your class `User` you have to note that the `id` is `private` so, your code should call public method to get the user id, so it has to be something like this:

```
  @Override
  @PreAuthorize("#user.getId() == authentication.getName()")
  void delete(@RequestParam(name="user", required=true)User user);
  .....
```

you have to call the public method as well to get the username from the principal.

Also, please note that you can make a call to a security check function to do more logic, for example:

```
  @Autowired
  private SecurityCheck securityCheck;

  ................

  @Override
  @PreAuthorize("@securityCheck.check(#user,authentication)")
  void delete(User user);
```

And in the SecurityCheck class can be difined like this:

```
@Component
public class SecurityCheck {


public boolean check(User user, Authentication authentication) {
    if(user == null)
        return false;
   if(user.getId().equals(authentication.getName()))    
       return true;
   // more logic ... 
   return false;
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that works. But now I cannot access the principal :`Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E: Method call: Method getUsername() cannot be found on java.lang.String type`

Comment: And I had to make the user into a parameter as well: `void delete(@Param("user") User user);`

Comment: I think you have to use authentication rather than principal

Comment: Unfortunately, it still thinks that the authentication object is a String: `EL1004E: Method call: Method check(com.example.User,java.lang.String) cannot be found on com.example.SecurityCheck type`

Comment: have you imported  'org.springframework.security.core.Authentication' ?

Comment: Yes, that exactly my import

Comment: I have edited my question, the behaviour seems to change depending on whether I call this endpoint with ROLE_USER or ROLE_ADMIN. Sometimes, it sees the object as a String and sometimes not.